# Function return function javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple demo:

```
function add(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Now when I call `add(1)(2)` it will give me `3`

but I want something like this:

`add(1)(2)(3)` -> 6

`add(1)(2)(3)(4)` -> 10

it means I can add more function if I want. How to write it?

Comment: a = array and your second function runs `for each`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to curry a function across an unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187590/how-to-curry-a-function-across-an-unknown-number-of-parameters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem elsewhere, but there the requirement was slightly different. Instead of having `add(1)(2)(3)` return 6, it was required to have `add(1)(2)(3)()` return 6.

Notice that the last invocation of the function does not have any arguments. This is important distinction because the function should either return another function that taken in a number as an argument or it should return the total of the arguments passed so far. Without the distinction of the last parameter being undefined (or NaN) it is not possible to decide whether to return a currying function or the total so far.

---

So I will assume that what you want is to have `add(1)(2)(3)()` return 6. Here's how you could do that:

- As already explained, the `add` function either returns another function that takes an argument if the current parameter is a number.
- If the current argument is undefined (or NaN) it returns the sum.
- You keep track of the sum using a variable `sum` that is available to the `total` function through closure.

```js
function add(x) {
  var sum = x;
  return function total(y) {
    if (!isNaN(y)) {  
      sum += y;
      return total;
    } else {
      return sum;
    }
  }
}

console.log(add(5)(2)());
console.log(add(5)(3)());
console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one array and pass to function and execute same function recursively

something like this

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

function add(a , i, sum) {
    if(i >= a.length ){ 
      return sum;
    } else {
      sum = sum + a[i];
      ++i;
      return add(a, i, sum)
    }
}
var b = add(arr ,i=0,sum = 0);
console.log(b)
```

Comment: My question is `function return function`, not like your :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with array. Only if someone googles for it since Nisargs answer is absolutely fine.

```
function add(a) {
    arrInt = a;
    return function total(arrInta) {
        b = 0;
        arrInt.forEach(element => {
            b = b + element;
        });
        return b;
     };
 }

 a = [1,2,3]

 console.log( add(a)());
 a = [1,2,3, 4]
 console.log( add(a)());
```

Which returns:

```
​​​6​​​​​ at ​​​add(a)​​​ ​quokka.js:14:1​

​​​​​10​​​​​ at ​​​add(a)​​​ ​quokka.js:16:1​
```

Comment: My question is `function return function`, not like your :)

Comment: @Khuong Than like this, but like I said only for help searching users :D Now its function return function