# How to add the function n number of arguments in Javascript? add(3)(8)(6)(10)

Tags: javascript

I need to add the function n number of arguments. Example : add(3)(8)(6)(10).

if it is only 2 arguments we can add the code like this. add(4)(5)

```js
function add(x){
    return function(y){
       return x+y;
    }
}
add(4)(5)
```

if it is n number of arguments of how can we do this?

Comment: You want `add(3)(8)(6)(10) === 27`, for any number of terms? That’s impossible. You can have something that acts like a number, but it won’t really be one (and that would be a terrible API).

Comment: Do you know `n` a priori?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187590/how-to-curry-a-function-across-an-unknown-number-of-parameters/39198247#39198247

Comment: Or even [Variadic curried sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5832891/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

The closer I can get to what you asked is this;

```js
function add(x){
    var next = function(y){
       return add(x + y)
    }

    next.result = x
    return next
}

console.log(add(4)(5).result)
console.log(add(4)(5)(1)(5).result)
console.log(add(3).result)
```

Here is a slightly different approach using objects, and IMO it is a lot more readable then `add(1)(2)(3)` since it is clear what operation you are performing in the subsequent steps. Also, this approach allows for extending with more operations, like minus for example.

```js
class Add {
    constructor (value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    add (anotherValue) {
        return new Add(this.value + anotherValue)
    }

    result () {
        return this.value
    }
}

function add (value) {
    return new Add(value)
}

var result = add(3).add(5).add(10).result()
console.log(result) // 18
```

Comment: The asker wants partial applications of functions, not method chaining.

Comment: Yeah, but what he wants is impossible (see Ryan comment). This is a much better way to achieve the same result, IMHO.

Comment: IMHO don't start the chain with `add()`.  Probably doing something like `calculator.startWith(3).add(5)` is more *Readable* and *Understandable* right off the bat.  That being said, this is still pretty cool.

Comment: Great suggestion, @ErikPhilips except for those uppercase letters haha :)

Comment: I'm primarily program in C#, I do it without thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is not known beforehand, I can say categorically it's not possible. If `n` is fixed, you can do something like (say, `n` is 4):

```
const add = first => second => third => fourth => first + second + third + fourth.
```

If you want to let `n` be flexible, your best bet is this

```
const add = (...additives) => {
  let result = 0;
  for (const additive of additives) {
    result += additive;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [**Ryan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ryan) suggested in his comment : `add(3)(8)(6)(10)` is impossible.

**Try this work around :**

```js
function add() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum = sum+arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

var res = add(3, 8, 6, 10);
console.log(res);
```