# How do you curry functions with named parameters?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a bit of code like this,

```
const createLogger = ({
  dispatch,
  frame,
  level,
  message,
}) => {
  dispatch(
    actions.debugLog.push({
      frame,
      level,
      message,
    }),
  )
}
```

**How would I be able to curry this function while retaining named parameters?**

and use it like

```
const userLogger = createLogger({
    dispatch: useDispatch(), 
    frame: "userController",
    level: "Warning"
    // ...potentially other top level keys
})


// user stuff happens

userLogger({ message: "User deleted profile" })()

// later 

const adminUserLogger = userLogger({ 
    frame: "adminUserController",
    dispatch: adminDispatch
})
```

The use case is that this will be called in certain areas of my application, cutting down on repeated code.

The arity is expected to grow (above is just an example) but I would also want to override certain keys. Let's say the I invoke the function with a certain set of preset keys, I'd like to maintain those but this time have a new `area`. The permutations for this increase for more complex portions (standard use case for currying).

Comment: Do you really want to curry it, or would a partial-application be more appropriate?

Comment: @Dai Can you explain a bit further on what you mean (I am still rusty on some fp related topics).

Comment: Also, is the object returned from `createLogger` a function or an object? If it's a function then it should be named `createLogFunction` and `userLogger` should be named `logUserMessage` (or similar). Functions are named are verbs and objects after nouns.

Comment: Please post more code btw - such as the definition of `dispatch`. Can you also rewrite your code as TypeScript instead of JavaScript? That would make things a LOT easier to follow!

Comment: Currently, I am showing you the function as it is in the application. It returns nothing, it is the same `dispatch` seen in `redux`, specifically using `redux-logic` here. Point noted about the variable names.

Comment: The implementation of dispatch and any of the type definitions are cursory information to the currying/partial problem at hand. I think that it is high level enough, I could post more code but that first function above is the entirety of the relevant code

Comment: Are potential other top-level keys to be put into the `debugLog` entry object, just like `frame` and `level`?

Comment: @AuxTaco yes, arity indeterminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the basic structure from [slebetman's answer to "How to curry a function across an unknown number of parameters"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198247/9029328), and combining objects instead of adding numbers:

```js
const createLogFunction = options => {
  function curryingLogFunction(newOptions) {
    if (newOptions !== undefined) {
      // add newOptions into options
      options = { ...options, ...newOptions };

      return curryingLogFunction;
    }

    // dispatch isn't part of the object pushed to debugLog, so get a
    // version of options that doesn't include it
    const { dispatch: _, ...optionsWithoutDispatch } = options;

    // for the snippet
    console.log(options.dispatch, optionsWithoutDispatch);
    //options.dispatch(
    //  actions.debugLog.push(optionsWithoutDispatch),
    //);
  }
  return curryingLogFunction;
}

const logUserAction = createLogFunction({
  dispatch: 'useDispatch()', // string for the snippet, function in your code
  frame: "userController",
  level: "Warning"
  // ...potentially other top level keys
});


// user stuff happens

logUserAction({
  message: "User deleted profile"
})();

// later 

const logAdminAction = createLogFunction({
  frame: "adminUserController",
  dispatch: 'adminDispatch'
});

logAdminAction({ message: 'message' })({ currying: 'works' })({ frame: 'override defaults' })()
```

Comment: Thanks! One other thing, do you think this is generally a good approach to a simple logging system? The idea that it builds upon successive calls. Conceptually and also how pretty it looks when read (without knowing its implementation). This is purely a style/implementation question.

Comment: @ParthianShotgun I don't have enough experience working with others' code to answer authoritatively. It seems reasonable enough to me, as long as the functions are named clearly.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming your "factory function" (`createLogger`) returns a function (`log`) which is then used by callers to log events, then I'll refer to it as `createLogFunction`).

(Using TypeScript):

```
type UseDispatch = 'auto' | true | false;
type Level       = 'Warning' | 'Error';

// This interface has all the required and optional named parameters of the original `actions.debugLog.push` function:
interface LogOptions {
    readonly dispatch: UseDispatch;
    readonly frame: string;
    readonly level: Level;
    readonly message: string;
    [propName: string]: any;
}

type LogFunction = ( opts: Partial<LogOptions> ) => void;
declare actions.debugLog.push: LogFunction; // so `actions.debugLog.push` has the type `LogFunction`.

// This function accepts a subset of `LogOptions` values and returns a new log function that also accepts a subset of LogOptions named parameters
function createLogFunction( factoryOpts: Partial<LogOptions>, innerLogFunc: LogFunction ): LogFunction {

    return function( invokeOpts: Partial<LogOptions> ): void {
        let combinedOptions: Partial<LogOptions> = {};
        combinedOptions = Object.assign( combinedOptions, factoryOpts );
        combinedOptions = Object.assign( combinedOptions, invokeOpts );

        innerLogFunc( combinedOptions );
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
let originalLogFunction: LogFunction = actions.debugLog.push;
originalLog( { message: "foo", level: 'Warning', dispatch: 'auto' } );

let logWarning = createLogFunction( { level: 'Warning', dispatch: 'auto' }, originalLogFunction );
logWarning( { message: "bar" } );

let noDispatchWarning = createLogFunction( { dispatch: false }, logWarning );
noDispatchWarning ( { message: "qux" } );
```