# How to get output of sum(1)(2,3)(4,5,6) without final call in currying javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, currying

How to implement a function **sum** which will take parameters like the below and should give the output of the total sum without calling it at the end with an empty parameter call.

```
sum(1,2..n)(5,6…n)…(n)
```

example:

```
console.log("output should be: ", sum(1)(2,3)(4,5,6)) // output should be: 21
```

Note:

1. I know we can use valueOf but that will only work if we are parsing the result in primitive value.
2. I don't want solution for `console.log(sum(1)(2,3)(4,5,6)()) // 21` as its solution I know which is:

```
function add(...args) {
      let a = args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      function sum(...args){
        let b = args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        if(b){
          return add(a+b)
        }
        return a
      }  
      return sum
}
```

3. Any help/guidance or reference by which it can be achieved will be helpful.

Comment: You can't if you want to infinitely curry, because you can't make a number callable, or a function a number

Comment: why dont you make your life easier and just do `sum(...args){ return args.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr ,0) }`

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not using `valueOf`, but there is this example you could look at. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187590/how-to-curry-a-function-across-an-unknown-number-of-parameters

Comment: @NickParsons So, I can conclude this is not possible until we provide some terminating conditions.

Comment: @Keith I was talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf
this can be used if I use the output somewhere like addition.
eg. sum(1)(2,3)(4,5,6) + 100 this will give 121